# Move everything from a k8s cluster to a new one

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, migration, cluster-computing

Is it possible to move every deployment on a running k8s cluster to another running k8s cluster?
I don't need to move cluster configurations, just every deployment, its pods, secrets, services, endpoints, pv/pvc, ingress etc. Everything that would be attached to a namespace and deleted in case that namespace gets deleted.

Comment: You cannot move PVs, unless you backup them and restore them. Everything else, you can you apply the same Yaml manifests, since it is stateless.

Comment: Feel free to update the status of the question. Let me know if the below answer helps to resolve your issue? I am happy to help you if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @**Jonas** suggested, except for PVs, **you can apply the same Yaml manifests to migrate every deployment from one kubernetes cluster to another cluster**. For PVs, you need to backup and restore PVs by referring to the official kubernetes doc on [Creating volume snapshot](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshots/) and [Restoring Volume from Snapshot Support](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshots/).

> Volume snapshots provide Kubernetes users with a standardized way to copy a volume's contents at a particular point in time without creating an entirely new volume. This functionality enables, for example, database administrators to backup databases before performing edit or delete modifications.

You can also use the [Velero](https://velero.io/docs/v1.2.0/), [pv-migrate](https://github.com/utkuozdemir/pv-migrate#use-cases) tool/kubectl plugin and similar [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24229) for more details, which will help you to easily migrate the contents of one Kubernetes PVC to another.

Comment: I'm currently working on it but I'm encountering a lot of issues. But this is the way yes, using pv-migrate and kubectl to export all the things necessary although a kubectl get all doesn't actually get me everything my namespace needs. Anything under the configs or networks category doesn't get exported. And pv-migrate needs to be done manually per namespace.